# USE_I18N = True - error: unpack requires a string argument of length 8

Tags: python, django

When I wrote in settings.py `USE_I18N = True`, then debug error appears:

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 129.782)
error: unpack requires a string argument of length 8
```

When I wrote `USE_I18N = False`, everything works fine.

What can be the problem ?

Comment: Could you show the whole traceback of the error?

Comment: The problem is that there is no Traceback.
I mean, I'm just trying to run in debug pycharm (Shift + F9) and get the message

`runnerw.exe C: \ Python27 \ python.exe "C: \ Program Files \ JetBrains \ PyCharm 2.7.2 \ helpers \ pydev \ pydevd.py" - multiproc - client 127.0.0.1 - port 34772 - file C :/ Users / Richard.Davis / smartfoto / manage.py runserver 8000
pydev debugger: process 5296 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 129.782)
error: unpack requires a string argument of length 8`
I tried to change the same thing on a dedicated server, but in the end got a 502 error

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Re-making and compiling messages files worked.

The situation occurred to me after undoing the removal of a django application folder in PyCharm (4.x). So re-doing those messages solved the issue.